# Hybrid between AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I was wondering if there is any hybrid EventWaitHandle that will auto-reset it's state as AutoResetEvent is doing when .Set() is invoked and simultaneously will allow everybody who did .WaitOne() to pass the same as ManualResetEvent is doing.

The only one solution i came up is a very ugly one to use ManualResetEvent and to do the follwoing:

```
event.Set();
Thread.Sleep(100);
event.Reset();
```

What is the better way to do this ?
Thanks.

**UPD:**
Thansk to Hans I came up with the following solution.
Looks like it works:

```
class HybridWaitHandle
{

    private bool signal = false;
    private readonly object locker = new object();
    private int blocked = 0;

    void WaitOne()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            blocked++;

            while (!signal) Monitor.Wait(locker);

            blocked--;

            if (blocked == 0)
                signal = false;
        }
    }

    void Set()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            signal = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If all you want is a bounded buffer, then you can just use `BlockingCollection` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx), as Hans mentioned. That will eliminate having to do all this fragile synchronization code. You might also look into `CountdownEvent`, which could do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use Monitor.PulseAll() instead.  Known as "bounded buffer", sample code [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx#S5).  Available in .NET 4 as BlockingCollection<>.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to say without knowing more about how you're using it, but it sounds like a counted semaphore might fit the problem fairly well. You release the semaphore N times. That lets N threads run. When N threads have been released, the semaphore is reset. Note that technically, this isn't necessarily N separate threads -- it could be 1 thread released N times.

As such, if you need/want to assure that you're releasing N separate threads, you may (for one possibility) want to create 2 separate semaphores, alternating between the two for consecutive steps of the process. N threads wait on the first semaphore. When you release it N times, each thread runs, and then waits on the *other* semaphore. Eventually all the threads will be released by the first semaphore and run, which will reset that semaphore.

Then you can do the next processing step using the other semaphore.

Note, however, that much of this runs somewhat contrary to how threads tend to work best. You're forcing all the threads to remain in lock-step, but they're generally at their best if you just let them run as "freely" as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Basically I have a producer-consumer scenario with multiple producers and one consumer. I have a buffer where produced data is stored and I want producers be blocked when buffer length exceeds threshold. Later when consumer frees buffer I want all blocked producers to be released allowing them to produce data and later again be blocked when threshold is exceeded.

Comment: @Egor: Yup -- a counted semaphore *would* work in that case. Rather than blocking all producers when the queue is full, I'd have a semaphore on pushing things into the queue, so if the queue is full, each producer can still produce an item, and only wait when it needs to put it in the queue.